# largest and smallest number using input while loop python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, max, min

This is my try to write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters `done`. Once `done` is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a `try/except` and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter `7`, `2`, `bob`, `10` and `4` and match the output below. But it's false. I need some help can someone explain my fault.

```
largest = 0
smallest = 0



while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num =="done": break
    try:
           fnum = float(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

    if largest == 0 or num >= largest: largest = num
    else: largest= largest
    if smallest == 0 or num <= smallest: smallest = num
    else: smallest= smallest

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: Just Fyi we have min/max builtin functions in this language

Comment: i know but  i really need to got this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, why don't you a `list` to store the values, then you can use the `min` and `max` methods:

```
nums = []

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : break
    try:
        fnum = float(num)

    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue

    nums.append(fnum)

largest = max(nums)
smallest = min(nums)

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `fnum` in those if statements, not `num`.